# WebKit - getting an HTML element by postion

Tags: html, webkit, position, html-treebuilder

Is there a way in WebKit to get an HTML element (from the DOM) by its position?
i.e. saying that I have an X,Y coordinates, I would like to "spy" the element behind it.

I am looking for a C++ API (in WebKit), and not a javascript way.

Thanks.